# RoR Request for Hacking. --- !ruby/hash\u003aActionDispatch\u003a\u003aRouting\u003a\u003aRouteSet\u003a\u003aNamedRouteCollection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Someone tried to 'check' my platform. I got this kind of request:

```
---- !ruby/hash\u003aActionDispatch\u003a\u003aRouting\u003a\u003aRouteSet\u003a\u003aNamedRouteCollection 'NSFTW;eval(%[c2xlZXAoMjUp].unpack(%[m0])[0]);' \u003a !ruby/object\u003aOpenStruct table\u003a \u003adefaults\u003a {}
```

The question is What he tried to do? What are the expectations after that request?

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, it looks like yaml serialized ruby code: Something like

ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection 'NSFTW;sleep(25);'

`eval(%[c2xlZXAoMjUp].unpack(%[m0])[0])` run in an `irb`-session outputs
`sleep(25)`

and finally, we have a ruby-`OpenStruct` object named `table` and a `defaults` property.

Does that match any service your platform offers?

Comment: I've seen this too. I think it's just a generic sniff.